# regex validation for experience

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to validate experience in javascript in data-parsley-pattern in the format yy/mm. I have tried with the below pattern

```
data-parsley-pattern="([0-5][0-9])([/])((0[0123456789]|10|11))"
```

If I give `09/03hjj` it's accepting but I have to check only two digits after `/`

Comment: Use anchors `^(?:([0-5][0-9])([/])((0[0123456789]|10|11)))$`

Comment: Thank u. Ya its working